# Reuse FormRequest authorize() for both edit() VIEW and update() METHOD

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-authorization, laravel-formrequest

As per the documentation of Laravel 8, I can create custom FormRequests and put my validation / authorization logic in there. Which works fine for routes like `store` and `update`. But before one can actually get to the `update` route one has to press save on the `edit` route (the edit `view`).

So for the `edit` route. There is nothing to validate (yet), as this is where users enter data into forms for validation (later on). But to decide whether a user can even get to the  `edit` FORM, I could reuse the same logic from the `authorize()` method in the form.

So how to reuse the `authorize()` bit from the custom `FormRequest` for the `edit` `view` `route`?

```
public function authorize()
{
    return $this->user()->can('update', $this->comment);
}
```

Or is there no way to do this, and must I rewrite/duplicate the line below?

`return $this->user()->can('update', $this->comment);`

Comment: Never, EVER, reuse a `FormRequest`, it is bad practice, it can get out of hands really fast, as the "accepted" answer shows, really bad code, that is a Juniors code, not a Seniors code. Don't do that, you are going to get bad habits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution could be to create a single PostRequest (or whatever name fits your case) and then handle authorization and rules differ depending on which method is being used. While maybe not best practices, it can help reduce code clutter.

Like the example below, only a `POST` request would check for a required comment in the validation, while you could still visit the edit and view routes without requiring any validation.

```
public function authorize()
{
    switch ($this->method()) {
        case 'GET':
            break;
        case 'POST':
            $this->user()->can('update', $this->comment);
            break;
        case 'PUT':
            break;
        case 'PATCH':
            break;
        case 'DELETE':
            break;
    }

    return true;
}

public function rules()
{
    switch ($this->method()) {
        case 'GET':
            return [];
        case 'POST':
            return [
                'comment' => 'required'
            ];
        case 'PUT':
            return [];
        case 'PATCH':
            return [];
        case 'DELETE':
            return [];
        default:
            return [];
    }
}
```

Comment: Smart idea, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As basically it's depend on different way you can use it authorize method because you can directly invoke in the specific method if you want.

```
public function update(Request $request, Post $post)
{
    $this->authorize('update', [$post, $request->category]);

    // The current user can update the blog post...
}
```